# How does SqliteBrowser determine that the data in a cell is a blob?

Tags: sqlite, heuristics

How does [sqlitebrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) determine that the data within a cell is a blob? For some data it will determine it to be a blob, but other data it will say it is not a blob. My example of this is a set of data where there are 10 doubles written out as a blob, yet it does not call it a blob. So I would really really like to know how it determines a cell to be a blob or not be a blob?

[image: Example of this]

Comment: Have you tried to check the code in GitHub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/issues/16 might be the better answer. As it seems, there is or was code to determine what to display: for short blobs like the ones shown in the example (with less than 1024 bytes), the second condition holds: if there is a \0 character, the data is just displayed as "BLOB".

Answer (score 0):

The [SQLite C API](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/funclist.html) has [two different functions](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) for binding a text value or a blob value to an INSERT statement, so *only* the writing application determines what the type of the value is.

The function [sqlite3_column_type()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) returns the type of a column's value in the current row; this is used by the browser.

The same mechanisms are also directly availabe in SQL:

```
> SELECT typeof('hello'), typeof(x'1256AB');
text|blob
```

Comment: I was more interested in the heuristic used to determine that a string is a blob.

Comment: There is no heuristic. Strings and blobs are distinct types; SQLite never silently changes the type of a value.

Comment: But in the picture above a column described as a blob has text in some of the cells. So how does it decide to put blob or the text in the cell?

Comment: In SQLite, columns do not have types. Each value has its own type.

Comment: Then how did it determine the specific type of a value

Comment: See the first sentence of my answer.